# Error "Trying to get property of non-object" with Custom Walker for wp_nav_menu

Tags: menus, errors, walker

I am trying to add some ARIA related stuff to the wp_nav_menu function. I use a custom walker class for this purpose:

```
class Walker_Nav_Menu_With_Aria extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
        function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
                $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
                $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"sub-menu\" role=\"group\">\n";
        }

        function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
                $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
                $output .= "$indent</ul>\n";
        }

        function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
                $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

                $class_names = $value = '';

                $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
                $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;

                $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
                $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

                $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args );
                $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

                // Add attributes for <li>
                $li_attributes  = ' role="treeitem"';
                $li_attributes .= ' aria-expanded="false"';

                $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names . $li_attributes .'>';

                $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
                $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
                $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
                $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';

                // Add attributes for <a>
                $attributes .= $depth == 0 ? ' tabindex="0"' : ' tabindex="-1"';

                $item_output = $args->before;
                $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
                $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
                $item_output .= '</a>';
                $item_output .= $args->after;

                $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
        }

        function end_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
                $output .= "</li>\n";
        }
}
```

I just copy-pasted the original Walker_Nav_Menu class and added stuff, but I am getting errors because the $args variable treated like an object is really an array. But the really weird thing is that this error persists, even if I pass in the original walker like this:

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location' => 'main-nav',
    'walker'         => new Walker_Nav_Menu,
) );
```

These are the error messages I get:

```
NOTICE: TRYING TO GET PROPERTY OF NON-OBJECT IN /USERS/RUDOLF/SITES/LOCALHOST/WP/WP-INCLUDES/NAV-MENU-TEMPLATE.PHP ON LINE 88
NOTICE: TRYING TO GET PROPERTY OF NON-OBJECT IN /USERS/RUDOLF/SITES/LOCALHOST/WP/WP-INCLUDES/NAV-MENU-TEMPLATE.PHP ON LINE 90
NOTICE: TRYING TO GET PROPERTY OF NON-OBJECT IN /USERS/RUDOLF/SITES/LOCALHOST/WP/WP-INCLUDES/NAV-MENU-TEMPLATE.PHP ON LINE 90
NOTICE: TRYING TO GET PROPERTY OF NON-OBJECT IN /USERS/RUDOLF/SITES/LOCALHOST/WP/WP-INCLUDES/NAV-MENU-TEMPLATE.PHP ON LINE 92
```

The lines look like this (In the original file!):

```
(88) $item_output = $args->before;
(89) $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
(90) $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
(91) $item_output .= '</a>';
(92) $item_output .= $args->after;
```

Comment: Do you get error if not passing walker at all? Arguments _should_ be object, I think that that is what inline docs say and what `wp_nav_menu()` passes.

Comment: No, if I just use the default `wp_nav_menu()` function without a walker, it works perfectly. Yeah, but why is it an array then? I even `var_dump`'ed it, no object.

Comment: I am not sure what is going on then, because passing `new Walker_Nav_Menu` should behave identically to not passing walker. Is anything else going on, any plugins hooking into / manipulating menu functionality?

Comment: I just did some additional testing, and I'm sure this is a WordPress bug. In my case, the nav menu I used wasn't assigned in the backend. Therefore the list pages fallback was used, it seems that then the args variable is an array. I will trace this to the source now, then tell you what I found.

Comment: If I correctly assign a menu, it works!

Comment: I first didn't see the answer below, look there for the solution.

Comment: I tried if(wp_nav_menu()) and the code works.

Comment: You do realize this question is two years old? :D But I created a ticket for it here: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/24587 It's still not fixed though, so feel free to discuss it over there!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I get this error when there are no menus defined or no menus set for the location at `Appearance->Menus`. When that occurs `wp_nav_menu` uses a page walker fallback.

1. The [fallback (default) for `wp_nav_menu`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L139) is `wp_walker_page`
2. which uses [`wp_page_menu`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/post-template.php#L887)
3. which uses [`wp_list_pages`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/post-template.php#L919)
4. which uses [`walk_page_tree`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/post-template.php#L847)
5. which uses [`Walker_Page`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/post-template.php#L945) not `Walker_Nav_Menu`.

And apparently the two walkers are not compatible. I don't know why it doesn't fail gracefully. That seems like a bug to me.

With a menu set at `wp-admin->Appearance->Menus`, your code works.

You can avoid the error by checking to see that there is a menu assigned to the location before trying to use the location.

```
$locations = get_nav_menu_locations();
if (0 !== $locations['main-nav']) {
  wp_nav_menu( array(
      'theme_location' => 'main-nav',
      'walker'         => new Walker_Nav_Menu_With_Aria,
  ) );
}
```

Or, if you'd prefer less antihistamine addled code ( thanks @Rarst ):

```
if (has_nav_menu('primary')) {
  wp_nav_menu( array(
      'theme_location' => 'primary',
      'walker'         => new Walker_Nav_Menu_With_Aria,
  ) );
}
```

Comment: Fallback is only used when all else fails to display pages. If menu works properly items are walked with [`walk_nav_menu_tree()`](http://queryposts.com/function/walk_nav_menu_tree/) which does use `Walker_Nav_Menu` by default.

Comment: Nice update! Didn't occur to me wrong function might be grabbing the walker (that's meh). Also there is [`has_nav_menu()`](http://queryposts.com/function/has_nav_menu/) for that check.

Comment: That is exactly what I just wanted to post :D The nav menu `$args` are converted to an object in `wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php` on line 145 by the `wp_nav_menu()` function. The `wp_page_menu()` function which is used as a fallback doesn't do that, but instead just passes the array to the Walker from the nav menu which needs the object.

If you just add a `$args = (object) $args` on the top of the `start_el` function of the Walker class, you can fix this. Where would be the right place to report this to the WordPress team?

Comment: @Rudolf core bugs should be reported at http://core.trac.wordpress.org/

Comment: The `WP_Post` object that is passed as `$item` is different, too (Because of this, the pages have no names and the list just consists of empty `<li>` elements). Some serious refactoring would be needed to make these two walkers compatible.

Answer (score 0):

use below code to repair :

```
add_filter( 'wp_get_nav_menu_object', 'override_wp_get_nav_menu_object', 10, 2 );
function override_wp_get_nav_menu_object( $menu_obj, $menu ) {

    if ( ! is_object( $menu_obj ) ) {
        $menu_obj = (object) array( 'name' => '' );
    }

    return $menu_obj;
}
```